# .Net class properties - get accessor - how much processing is too much?

Tags: .net, properties

I've always had this feeling that a `get` accessor should generally be a fast lookup operation for a given value. It may incur a one-time calculation which is then cached for future lookups, but for the most part should try to return a stored value.

In the case where every lookup requires some variable-length calculation I am inclinded to write a method `GetFoo()` which sort of subtly implies that there may be some processing involved to retrieve the value.

Is this a bad practice? Are there any guidelines as to what (if any) amount of processing should or should not be expected when calling a `get` accessor?

Comment: get ends up as a get_X method internally anyhow, I beleive.

Comment: Yes it does, but the point is the way it is represented to the developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Framework guidelines are a good source for these kind of considerations.  Deciding between a property and a method is [covered here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054.aspx).  The advice is quite sound.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about guidelines, I just apply common sense.  If I think the act of getting the property is ***non-trivial***, it gets a method.  Non-trivial could still be quick.

I think this makes it a little easier to digest for other developers.  What with auto-properties and such, the property itself, in my opinion should just be the encapsulator of a field with perhaps some cross-cutting concern code (simple validation, authentication, etc).

One guideline I remember seeing once was that property values shouldn't change between calls unless changed directly.  If it changes, it goes in a method.  Not sure if I agree with that one.

At the end of the day, they are just guidelines :-) and pulling them out into methods is certainly **not** bad practice.